# Set environment variables in .htaccess based on TLD

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, environment-variables

I'm trying to set environment variables in my `.htaccess` file based on the top level domain of the server. But after there is a match for the condition, the `.htaccess` file does not execute further.

If there is no domain matched,`_rooturl_` is set but `_rootfolder_` is not. However, when a domain is matched `_rootfolder_` is set but `_rooturl_` is not. This also applies to any other redirects defined after that.

```
(...)

<If "req('Host') =~ /domain.com/ || req('Host') =~ /localhost/">
    RewriteRule .* - [E=_rootfolder_:www.domain.com]
</If>

<If "req('Host') =~ /domain.de/">
    RewriteRule .* - [E=_rootfolder_:www.domain.de]
</If>

RewriteRule .* - [E=_rooturl_:domainname]

(...)
```

TL;DR, I want my code to execute after passing the IF conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this block of rules totally based on `mod_rewrite` rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (localhost|domain\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=_rootfolder_:www.domain.com]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.de [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=_rootfolder_:www.domain.de]

RewriteRule ^ - [E=_rooturl_:domainname]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with mod_setenvif:

```
SetEnvIf Host "(localhost|domain\.com)" _rootfolder_=www.domain.com
SetEnvIf Host "domain\.de" _rootfolder_=www.domain.de
SetEnvIf Host ^ _rooturl_=domainname
```

> But after there is a match for the condition, the `.htaccess` file does not execute further.

Although that shouldn't happen with the directives you posted. It should "work" as intended. But this may depend on what other directives you have that depend on these env vars. And to some extent precisely what expressions and directives you are using.

There are a few potential issues here:

- `<If>` containers change the order of processing. The contents of `<If>` blocks are generally [merged *very* late](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging), however, mod_rewrite directives are still processed *before* mod_rewrite directives in the same context, regardless of where the `<If>` container(s) appear in the order of directives.
- Unless you enable mod_rewrite inheritance (eg. `RewriteOptions Inherit`), the mod_rewrite directives in later `<If>` blocks completely override mod_rewrite directives in earlier `<If>` blocks. (In the same way mod_rewrite directives in a subdirectory `.htaccess` file completely override mod_rewrite directives in a parent `.htaccess` file.) This is OK if the `<If>` expressions are mutually exclusive or you expect later directives to override (and not *add to*) earlier directives.